# Spring thymeleaf Form url cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I want to know how to transfer parameters in spring form mvc platform.
First, Below code is spring form java file.

```
public class PostForm {

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=30, message="type id within 30 limits")
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max=100, message="type id within 100 limits")
    private String Content;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return Content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

And the next file is the bounded edit.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Blog modification</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Please, Modifiy.</h1>
<form method="post" th:object="${postForm}">
    <div><label for="title">title</label></div>
    <input id="title" type="text" name="title" th:value="*{title}" />
    <span class="formError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}">Input title is wrong</span>

    <div><label for="content" th:value="*{title}">Content</label></div>
    <textarea name="content" rows="20" width="200" th:value="*{content}"></textarea>
    <span class="formError" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}">Input content is wrong</span>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Modify" />
        <a href="index.html" th:href="@{/posts}">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Input link url to form is like below,

```
    <td>
        <a href="posts/edit.html" th:href="@{posts/edit/__${post.id}__}">edit</a><br/>
        <a href="posts/edit.html" th:href="@{posts/edit/__${post.id}__}">delete</a>
    </td>
```

But the exception is thrown in the spring mvc controller codes.

```
@RequestMapping("/posts/edit/{id}")
    public String edit(PostForm postForm) {
        return "posts/edit/{id}"; //This line throws exception.
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/posts/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String edit(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @Valid PostForm postForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        Post p = postService.findById(id);
        postForm.setTitle(p.getTitle());
        postForm.setContent(p.getBody());

        .....
```

The exception is

```
ERROR 4024 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "posts/edit/{id}": Error resolving template "posts/edit/{id}", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "posts/edit/{id}", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:870) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar:3.0.9.RELEASE]
```

I have no idea how to transfer parameter in Spring Thymeleaf form template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sprig MVC, when @ReqeustMapping annotation with GET Method is called, it tries to find the html template with the name defined in the return value.

```
@RequestMapping("/posts/edit/{id}")
public String edit(PostForm postForm) {
    return "posts/edit/{id}"; //This line throws exception.
}
```

So here you must return the name of the html template in the resources folder (not the url)

So I guess it's supposed to be

```
@RequestMapping("/posts/edit/{id}")
public String edit(PostForm postForm) {
    return "views/mytemplate";
}
```

The error obviously indicates that it can't find the template under the resources folder. What your code does is try to locate the thymeleaf template in the 'edit' folder under 'posts' folder under the resources folder with the name of '{id}' but that's not there so it throws the error.

My suggestion is to change the return value of the GET method as I mentioned above.

If you need to pass any parameters to the view, use Model class. 
If the parameters' value must be calculated from the {id} then you can use @PathVariable to map the id to a parameter.

```
@RequestMapping("/posts/edit/{id}")
public String edit(@PathVariable(value="id") String id, Model model) {
    // do something here to get values using the id
    ....

    model.addAttribute("parameter1", parameter1);

    return "views/mytemplate";
}
```

By the way you don't need PostForm parameter in the GET method since it does not pass any postForm parameters in the body when it's called. You can leave it blank.

Hope this helps, have fun coding! :)